# Does Ibn Umar define Qaza in Sunan Abu Dawud 4193?(Sunnah.com reference)

Tags: hadith-interpretation, uloom-al-hadith

The translation of the hadith is written as:

> "Narrated Ibn Umar: The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) forbade qaza'. Qaza' means having part of a boy's head shaved and leaving part unshaven." 
> **[ [Sunnah Ref: Sunan Abu Dawud 4193](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4193) ]**

I am having trouble deciding if the meaning of Qaza here is what Ibn Umar is reported to have said or if the writer, Abu Dawud is giving his opinion. Who is speaking here?

thanks

Comment: What makes you think the statement is not from ibn 'Umar?

Comment: Keep in mind that Abu Dawud's comments are always explicitly prefaced by "Abu Dawud said."

Comment: @medi1saif just a suspicion i felt, if Abu Dawud did write that of his own opinion then he may have written it well below the actual hadith but in the online copy that gap would've been closed, making it less obvious that those are abu dawud's words. Again, it was just a suspicion.  As "The Z" pointed out, those comments are always prefaced  with "abu dawud said". On that note, why is abu dawud writing in the 3rd person about himself?

Comment: It is not abu Dawod who has written in the 3rd person about himself, but all ahadith compilations have been reported to us via intermediate so the student of abu Dawod who reported it added abu Dawod's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of Qaza' is at least the statement of Nafi' who narrated this hadith from Ibn Umar, as seen in the version of Saheeh Muslim:

> قال قلت لنافع وما القزع قال يحلق بعض رأس الصبي ويترك بعض
>
> I said to Nafi: What is Qaza'? He said: This means having a part of a boy's head shaved and leaving a part unshaven.
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2120a)</sup>

And there is no hindrance that the statement or its meaning goes upto Ibn Umar and the Prophet ﷺ as supported by:

> عن ابن عمر أن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم رأى صبيا حلق بعض رأسه وترك بعض فنهى عن ذلك وقال ‏ ‏ احلقوه كله أو اتركوه كله
>
> Ibn Umar narrated that the Prophet ﷺ saw a boy, part of whose head had been shaven and part had been left. He forbade that and said: "Shave all of it, or leave all of it."
>
> <sup>— [Nasai](https://sunnah.com/nasai:5048) and [Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4195)</sup>

---

**Ref:**

> هذا التفسير من كلام نافع كما في رواية مسلم
>
> <sup>— [Awn al-Mabood Sharh Sunan Abi Dawood](https://shamela.ws/book/5760/3741)</sup>

> وأخرجه أبو داود والنسائي وفي سياقه ما يدل على مستند من رفع تفسير القزع
>
> <sup>— [Fath al-Bari](https://shamela.ws/book/1673/6000)</sup>

Comment: Note that Bukhari's narration indicates the explanation is by Ubaidullah ibn al-Hafs: https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5920

Comment: @TheZ in fact scholars tend to say that 'Ubaidallah's explanation is based on Nafi's explanation, it is just more detailed and part of it is certainly as staetd in the ahdith fo Muslim a statement of Nafi'.